# How to find features with NULL values?

Tags: qgis, thematic-map

I have a layer to analyze and I want to create a thematic map with rule based feature. There is a strange behaviour. I want to find all objects with no data (NULL). All empty objects. The zero value for me is a value. I write:

> namefield = ''

The result is zero but I have 47 objects with NULL value. This is an error. The strange behaviour is if I write:

> namefield != ''

The result is 56 objects. This rule works.
It is impossible to find objects with no data but qgis find only objects with a value.

Is this a bug or a feature?

It is a bug for me!

I use qgis 1.8

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

NULL is not equal to ''. That's why the query doesn't return what you are looking for.

Try

```
namefield IS NULL
```